# Why running POST variable through CI XSS Filter truncate base64 string?

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, xss

I have a base64 encoded string like so:
`eyJjb3VudCI6IjAiLCJzdmNubyI6IjI0OTAiLCJzdGFydGR0IjoiMjAxNi0wNS0xNiAxMToxOTowMC4wIiwiaW5zdGFsbF9uYW1lIjoiIiwiY29ubmVjdGl2aXR5dGhyb3VnaGxpc3QiOiIiLCJyZXZlbnVlY2l0eSI6IiIsIm9iX2J5dGVzb3V0IjoiMCIsImN1c3RvbWVydHlwZSI6IiIsImNhbmNlbGR0IjoiIiwidXNlc3VtIjoiZmFsc2UiLCJhY3RjYXQiOiIyIiwiYmFsYnl0ZXNpbiI6Ii0xIiwicGtndHlwZSI6Ik8iLCJwa2dpZCI6Ik9TQjRtYnBzNDBHQjFtYnBzVUwiLCJpbnN0YWxsX3dlYiI6IiIsInBvZCI6IiIsInN0YXR1cyI6IjAiLCJiYWxzZWNvbmRzIjoiLTEiLCJjb3VudHJ5bm8iOiIiLCJpbnN0YWxsX2NpdHkiOiIiLCJpbnN0YWxsX2VtYWlsIjoiIiwic2Vjb25kYXJ5cG9kY29kZSI6IiIsImFjdG5vIjoiNjA1MTMiLCJtb25leWJhbCI6IiIsImFjdG5hbWUiOiJPc2JuZXQiLCJkb21ubyI6IjIwIiwibXVsdGkiOiJ0cnVlIiwibGFzdG1pbGVubyI6IiIsImV4cGlyZWR0IjoiIiwic3RhcnREYXRlIjoiMjAxNi0wNS0xNiAxMToxOTowMC4wIiwic3ZjdHlwZSI6IkludGVybmV0IEFjY2VzcyIsImluc3RhbGxfcGhvbmUiOiIiLCJpbnN0YWxsX2FkZHJlc3MiOiIiLCJyYXRlUGxhbiI6Ik9TQjRtYnBzNDBHQjFtYnBzVUwiLCJyYWRkZXB0Y29kZSI6IiIsImluc3RhbGxfcGluIjoiIiwib2JfYnl0ZXNpbiI6IjAiLCJzZXNjb3VudCI6IjEiLCJzdmNkZXNjciI6Ik9TQjRtYnBzNDBHQjFtYnBzVUwiLCJyZW5ld2R0IjoiIiwic3Vic25vIjoiMTkxMzQzNiIsInNhbWVhc2JpbGwiOiJ0cnVlIiwiaW5zdGFsbF9yZW1hcmtzIjoiIiwiZG9taWQiOiJvc2JuZXRicm9hZGJhbmQiLCJpbnN0YWxsX2ZheCI6IiIsImFjdGlkIjoib3NibmV0IiwiY3BubyI6IiIsImFjdHN0YXR1cyI6IjAiLCJwb3J0bm8iOiIiLCJwcmltYXJ5cG9kY29kZSI6IiIsImV4dGVybmFsaWQiOiIiLCJjcmVhdGVkdCI6IjIwMTYtMDUtMTYgMTE6MTk6NDIuMCIsImRldmljZSI6IiIsImJhbGJ5dGVzb3V0IjoiLTEiLCJvYl9zZWNvbmRzIjoiMCIsImV4cGlyeWR0IjoiMjAxNi0wNi0xNSAxMToxOTowMC4wIiwiQ3VzdG9tZXIiOnsibmFtZSI6Ik9zYm5ldCIsImVtYWlsIjoibmFyZXNoLmNoYXZhbjg5QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInBob25lIjoiIiwiYWRkcmVzcyI6IlN1cGVyIE1hcmtldCIsImNpdHluYW1lIjoiQmFuZ2Fsb3JlIn0sInJlbmV3YWxEYXRlIjoiIiwibmV4dFJlbmV3YWxEYXRlIjoiMTUgSnVuIDIwMTYiLCJwYWNrYWdlQW10IjoiMyIsIlRheCI6MC40MzUsIlRheFBlcmNlbnQiOiIxNC41IiwiY29udmVuaWVuY2VGZWUiOjAuMDY4NywiVG90YWwiOjMuNTAzNywicGFja2FnZVRvdGFsIjozLjQzNX0=`

When I `POST` it to PHP server and receive it like

`$base64String = $this->input->post('base64', TRUE);`

I get `eyJjb 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`

(with a space and carriage return after first 5 characters). However when I remove the `TRUE` flag from CI's `post()` method, I get an intact base64 string.

Is this a flaw in CI's XSS filter or XSS filter works that way? :/

EDIT: Space and Carriage return after first 5 characters is not generic. It happens for this particular string. I have not tried with any other base64 string yet.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about why this issue but if you post base64 then you should use JSON.stringify.

```
var finalCanvas2 = finalCanvas.toDataURL();
data += '&Base64=' + JSON.stringify(finalCanvas2);
```

and at receiver end you just need to
fetch post and filer.

```
$this->input->post('Base64');  
    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $Base64);
    list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    file_put_contents('first.png' , $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The XSS is over aggressive. I managed to solve this by editing system/core/Security.php

Remove `'on\w*'` from `$evil_attributes`